# Proving that the Riemann zeta function is zero free on Re=1 using the prime number theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function, prime-number-theorem

Is $\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+\frac{-s}{s-1}$ an analytic continuation, holomorphic for $Re\ s > 0,\ s\neq 1$, of $f(s)=s\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\psi(x)-x}{x^{s+1}}\mathrm{d}x$?

If so: Let $s_{0}$ such that $Re\ s_{0} = 1,\ s_{0}\neq 1$.

Can I conclude

\begin{align}
\lim_{s\to s_{0}}(s-s_{0})f(s) = \lim_{s\to s_{0}}(s-s_{0})\left[\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+\frac{-s}{s-1}\right]
\end{align}
?

Bonus: Under the wrong assumption that $s_{0}$ is a root of order m of the zeta function, I would expect $\lim_{s\to s_{0}}(s-s_{0})\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = -m$. The book I'm reading asks me to prove $\lim_{s\to s_{0}}(s-s_{0})f(s) = m$ contrary to what I just "showed". What am I doing wrong?

Write $s_{0}=1+it_{0}$. Then combining the above result with the fact that
\begin{align}
\lim_{\sigma\to 1^{+}}(\sigma - 1)f(\sigma + it_{0}) = 0,
\end{align}
a result obtained using the prime number theorem, results in a contradiction which proves that the prime number theorem implies $\zeta(1+it)\neq 0,\ t\neq 1$.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit: Removed the original question as suggested. Also: $s_{0}$ is supposed to be a root of order m, forgot that detail.

Comment: I'm actually a little sad to see close votes. I have a sense that this is not likely to be answered at Math.SE, not because nobody there can do it, but because it will get lost in the crowd.

Comment: Well, I'm asking strangers to spend a decent amount of their time on my problem - I can't expect answers. Yet I'd be really really glad if anyone would take the time as I want to use this proof in my thesis..

Comment: Is this link any useful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863015/prime-number-theorem-and-the-riemann-zeta-function  (for the question in the title of the post)

Comment: This question at MSE would not get “lost in the crowd” any more than other questions. The OP could ask it there without all these edits: combine them to one focused question.

Comment: Sadly no. I tried searching for similar questions here, but mine is a rather specific one, as I want to prove something the way a books wants me to do it. And yes, I guess the title of my question is a little misleading now that I edited it.. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @KConrad, tried my best!

Comment: @KConrad Well, that's consistent with my point: lots of questions there sink without a trace. But maybe it'd be different now that you're looking.

Comment: I am waiting for it to appear on MSE, but have not seen anything yet. If the OP posts the question there, indicate a link to it in a comment here.

Comment: Just consider the book has a typographical error since, as you know, $\lim_{s \to s_0} (s-s_0)g'(s)/g(s) = {\rm ord}_{s=s_0}g$.  So your whole post is just about a printing error.Also, your proof does not really involve a contradiction: your argument never used the condition $m \not= 0$: you prove $m = 0$, and a meromorphic function with order of vanishing 0 at a point is holomorphic and nonvanishing at the point.

Comment: Take a look at Zagier's presentation of a short proof of the prime number theorem due to D. J. Newman here https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2975232/fulltext.pdf . See lemma IV specifically. Hope that helps.